# Why is ModelState invalid if a submitted empty date defaults to default value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a view where I load a form to update a user. When I populate my view model `UpdateUserViewModel` with data to show on the page, the `Info` property on `UserModel` is null. This is expected because there simply isn't a record for it in the database, so it is not retrieved. However, I still add hidden fields for its two properties because when I post the form, I want the `Info` property to be created with default values, which does happen.

```
public UpdateUserViewModel {
    public UserModel User { get; set; }
}
    
public class UserModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public InfoModel Info { get; set; }
}

public class InfoModel {
    public DateTime InfoDate { get; set; }
    public string ConcurrencyToken { get; set; }
}
```

Posting the form results in `ModelState.IsValid` to be false for the `InfoDate` property on the `InfoModel`. It gives the error message `The value '' is invalid`. But this does not make sense because when I inspect the posted model's `InfoDate` value, I see it is the default min date `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`.

I've thought about making the `InfoDate` nullable, but that doesn't make sense because I'm required to map this property onto a business layer model and set it to the default date anyway. I also don't understand why it's showing that error when it clearly defaults to a value.

Why am I getting `The value '' is invalid` when I see that the empty date the form submitted has successfully defaulted to `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM`? How can I fix this?

I'm thinking maybe it's looking specifically at what value the user had set it to in the field instead of what ends up as the value of the property? But if so, why would it care? I don't have any validation attribute on `InfoDate`, such as `[Required]`.

Comment: I've not tried this, but you could try pre-populating the `InfoDate` property with the `default` value so it's never empty and you won't get an exception because `DateTime` is not nullable.
`public DateTime InfoDate { get; set; } = default`.

If you then ever get an `InfoModel` from your DB that default value should be overriden.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it did not work. I think it may be because I'm not initializing the `Info` property on `UserModel`, although I'm also not sure I want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When binding data in client side,it will get value from ModelState prior to Model .Try to add `ModelState.Clear()` and `TryValidateModel(xxx)` before you check the ModelState.And then you will not get `The value '' is invalid`.

```
ModelState.Clear();
TryValidateModel(MyProperty);
var IsValid=ModelState.IsValid;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. It definitely adds a weirdness into the code because it feels hacky, but the real issue may be the quality of my code.